# Circuit Simplification

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, resistance

Calculate the current shown by the ammeter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMlfzL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How do we solve this using delta-wye transformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams. And here I provide the graphical exaplanation.

[image]

Blue section consistst of two 10R resistors in parallel --> 5R

Green section consistes of two 10R resistors in parallel --> 5R

Blue + green are combined together in series --> 5+5 = 10R

Now we add the yellow section to it. 5R, 5R, 10R --> 2R

I = V/R = 5 A

Answer (score 6):

The two sets of 10Ω are in parallel and series, so 10Ω || 10Ω + 10Ω || 10Ω = 5Ω + 5Ω = 10Ω. And now that is in parallel with the two 5Ω, so you get 2Ω. And that into 10V is 5A.

Comment: Which two 10-Ω resistors are in parallel? How do you find out?

Comment: Both of the sets on the horizontal axis are. The nodes on the left and right of the network are connected to both parallel sets, as is the node in the center.

Comment: Re-draw the circuit with the four diagonal resistors horizontal, then all should become clear.  The circuits in this sort of exercise are often drawn in a way intended to confuse the student.

Answer (score 2):

Use "something else"- symmetry.

It's easy to see that the parallel resistance is 2\$\Omega\$ so the current follows to be 5A.

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers already.  This is simply another approach which does not involve finding the equivalent resistance.

First, one can see by inspection that the there is \$2A\$ through each \$5\mathrm \Omega\$ resistor since there is \$10V\$ across each.

Second, due to the symmetry of the \$10\mathrm \Omega\$ resistor network,
the voltage across each resistor must be the same.  Since there is a 10V source, this is only possible if the voltage across each \$10\mathrm \Omega\$ resistor is \$5V\$.

(This may not be immediately obvious so, if it isn't, consider that, by symmetry, the voltage at the node connecting the four \$10\mathrm \Omega\$ resistors must be \$5V\$.)

Thus, there is \$0.5A\$ through each \$10\mathrm \Omega\$ resistor.

Then, by KCL at either end of the resistor network, the total current must be

$$2A + 2A + 0.5A + 0.5A = 5A$$

Answer (score 0):

The circuit is redrawn in **1**, below.

Then considering in **2** that the wire connecting R2, R3 ,R4, and R5 is across the output of a balanced bridge, there's no voltage across it and no current through it, so in **3**, below, it's gone.

Then, in **3**, R1, R2,and R4 are in parallel as are  R3, R5, and R6,  so in **4**, below, they reduce down to a pair of 4 ohm resistors in parallel.

In **5**, below, the pair reduce down to a single instance of 2 ohms in series with 10 volts, which will force 5 amperes through that resistance.

[image]

Comment: Don't bridges go the other way, i.e. across the supply rather than along it?